# Bootstrap: Wrong button font color after clicking on <a>-tag

Tags: css, firefox, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using twitter bootstrap (v3.3.7) and the following button was displayed just fine:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadContent(...); return false;" class="btn btn-primary">Open</a>
```

After clicking on a link like this

```
<a href="somefile.pdf" target="_blank">File</a>
```

the font-color of the button turns black. Reloading does not help, i have to delete all history data, cache etc.
This problem occurs in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari.

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this problem?
I hope it's possible to fix this without overriding the styles of the button.

EDIT
to clarify: the second link is not the same as the first one. So the style of the first button (a styled a-tag) changes after clicking on an other a-tag. In the developer tool it says that the font of the first button should be black, but it is white and therefore invisible, as the button is white, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without overriding the styles of the button. What you're seeing is `a:visited` at work. You need to override this CSS rule to be the same as the unvisited `a` in order for the link to look the same both before and after.

Comment: But why is the a:visited rule not working only after opening a tab in a new window?

Comment: @PercyDowning It _is_ working. `a:visited` is applied on top of the `a` rule when the `href` attribute of the `a` tag refers to a page in the user's browser history.

Comment: Correct. But why is the a:visited only applied, when an other random a-tag with target="_blank" was visited before? Furthermore the font-color is white, but in the developer tool it says that it should be black (what btw is the correct color it actualy should be).

Comment: @PercyDowning Perhaps you could create a MCVE? Try hosting a saved version of your web page and see if it still happens. Cut out half the page, then the other half, then some CSS rules etc. until you've narrowed it down to a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example. That'll make this problem much easier to solve.